# RxJS / wait for an event to go through the entire pipeline before emitting the next

Tags: javascript, rxjs, queue, rxjs6

I am looking to build an rxjs pipeline that emits the next event only if the current one has gone through the entire pipeline (FIFO struct).

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { map, filter } = rxjs.operators;

// the event `2` should only be emitted
// when the event `1` has reached the end of the pipeline.
// and so on and so fort
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]).pipe(
  map((n) => n ** 2),
  filter((n) => n % 2),
).subscribe(console.log);


/**
-1-------|
-2-------|-1
...
**/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha512-DRDXreq+zyiPhlKTfJ5pgzWRn+6SgJ7cPoRxMNksyHmUEOjKiKIoqvssNYNwknpvVbQsVN5hlhh3sp0rxbU7Bg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: It looks to me that, in your example which by the way is fully synchronous, this is exactly what happens: 2 enters the pipeline only once 1 has notified in the subscription provided function. If things are async, then maybe the `exhaustMap` operator can help. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for reassembles me some kind of ["backpressure" in RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md#controlled-observables) which is not maintained any more and RxJS doesn't provide any operator (or Observable creation method) that would do exactly what you're describing.

However, you could do the same using `zip()` operator because it'll emit only when all source Observables emit the same number of `next` emissions.

```
import { Subject, zip, from, map, startWith } from 'rxjs';

const done$ = new Subject<void>();

zip(
  from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
  done$.pipe(
    startWith(void 0), // trigger the first emission
  ),
)
  .pipe(
    map(([value]) => value),
  )
  .subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
    setTimeout(() => done$.next(void 0), 500);
  });
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-oqzeqx?devtoolsheight=60